# Clarification of [[pure]] in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

Reading the most recent proposal for a standard C++ attribute [[[pure]]](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3744.pdf) I was left with a number of questions:

1. Could a [[pure]] function read const globals?
2. Could a [[pure]] function read static const variables?
3. Could a [[pure]] function write but not read pointer or reference variables (and still return void possibly)?

Comment: And what about a const reference to an object that might change?  To resolve this, we need to bring in the concept of an immutable variable into C++.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: How would that different from a `constexpr` variable?

Comment: No difference, @BenjaminBannier.  I forgot about `constexpr`.  Thanks for reminding me!  I'm surprised I forgot this, I was quite excited about it when I first learned about it.  Perhaps the question should be edited to say `constexpr` instead of `const`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[pure]], If I recall right, needs to be 100% certain that a particular input should always return a specific output.  Considering a const globals and static const globals should never change states, it should be ok.  Finally, reading a pointer that *could* change states would not be a pure function.  If you write to pointers accessed elsewhere, then it has a side effect and is not [[pure]].

You have to ask yourself if the function result is dependent on an extraneous variables' state, and if you answer yes, it is not [[pure]].  You also have to ask yourself if an input can have an effect on anything other than it's return value.  If that is true, then it is not [[pure]]

Comment: +1 Another way of stating the last paragraph is that it is [[pure]] only if different calls with the same argument are guaranteed to always yield the same result and cause no side effects

Comment: Yeah, the 'cause no side effects' IRR was a direct definition in the journal I read.  I forgot to mention that aspect in my answer, which I will now edit.

Comment: So, is [[pure]] basically the definition of a mathematical function?

Comment: @JosuéMolina Well, sort of.  Mathmatical fucntions demand it passes the verticle line test (one input-> one output) but a pure function can have 10 outputs as long as all 10 rely only on the input and not the state of any accessed variables (that might change).

Comment: What about something that could be different for each run-through of the program, like a global that upon initialization stored the date and time that the program started, but didn't change after that?  It wouldn't be consistent across runs of the program, but WOULD if run many times at once.  Edit: I mean a function that also accessed that, would the FUNCTION be pure?

Comment: @Kevin: This is an annotation to the compiler, and the intention is to allow it to further optimize your code. If the function reads a global, the program calls the function with the same arguments multiple times, the compiler would be able remove all but the first invocation. If the global state changes the results if this optimization is applied or not would be different, and the behavior of the program starts depending heavily on the optimizer... bad idea

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas - From what you're saying, the optimization would work fine.  I was more meaning from a testing perspective, where "pure" functions would be easier to test (theoretically) but in my theoretical it would be a bit harder again.  But the compiler optimization would be fine.  Thanks for clarifying it though.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas exactly how I see it.  It's for a compiler to optimise something like `int a = func(foo) + 3*func(foo);`  If `func` is `[[pure]]` then it can substitute the value returned by `func(foo)` otherwise the states could change between each call to `func`, and `func(foo)` can not be optimized away.

Comment: @Kevin: The C library provided in gcc/linux already does this with it's own set of attributes. In particular in `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p); ++i) { std::cout << p[i]; }` the compiler will move the call to `strlen` outside of the loop and evaluate it only once. Back to the previous comment, if the function depends on external mutable state, even if today it does not change, it might change in the future (say your application reloads the config or what not) and the optimization would break as subsequent calls would ignore the changes in the parameters.

Comment: @Kevin: Regarging testing, you *know* your code and you write the test driver. Whether the function is tagged as `[[pure]]` or not is a completely different issue.